# Is it possible to go from localhost to external adress

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I can connect to my localhost and get info from a local phpMyAdmin database.

Now I want from a php file, that is stored on my local computer, but now the php file refers me to go to an external website:

```
<?php

//mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
mysql_connect("http://eternal website","username","password");

mysql_select_db("dlvplant_portret_v1");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE voornaam LIKE '%%'");
//$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE voornaam ='""'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();

?>
```

I tried the link and copy/paste the username and pass and I use the good website link. (the link brings me at the myPhpAdmin login from the server). So everything works and is filled in good. But when I try to connect with my android phone (from phone to local comp's php file) then the php file refers me to go to external webpage, but it says: `Host is unknown`

Is it even possible to go from local to external and back again?

[image]

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use plain ip address(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) or single "DOMAIN.SOMETHING" instead of "http://DOMAIN.SOMETHING"

```
mysql_connect("IPADDRESS","username","password");
```

Answer (score 3):

You *can* connect to external MySQL hosts - but you do not use the **HTTP** protcol for it. And external access needs to be enabled on the MySQL server.

Comment: meaning - you need that external MySQL database to allow you to connect and a firewall port must be open for you on the server

Comment: @thedom Where to find this option? I got privaleges  ALL on YES.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter Where to find this option? I got privaleges ALL on YES.

Comment: Are you checking this on the remote host? Log in to __PHPMyAdmin__ and check the rights of your user. Be sure to allow it not only from localhost but also from remote. So setting __host__ to ``%`` you should be fine (assuming that the MySQL service is reachable from Internet/external).

Comment: @thedom Added a picture, and yes, I can reach it trough my webbrowser

Comment: Looks quite fine! Try to connect to the server with the servers host name but without ``http://``. e.g ``mysql_connect('external-host.com', 'username', 'password');``